# Parkerian Hexad - Confidentiality Vs Possession of Data

Tags: security

Considering the Parkerian Hexad, what is the difference between confidentiality and possession of data? They both are concerned with the protection of data from unauthorised individuals. Any practical examples to illustrate the answer would be helpful, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parker in his seminal work Fighting Computer Crime, proposed a new model that extended the CIA triad by introducing three additional non overlapping (atomic) attributes or threats.

Confidentiality was extended to include Possession/Control. An adversary may steal a memory stick with you private key on it, but **they may not have your pass phrase to use it** (OR they may decide not to use it voluntarily, even though they have your key). The confidentiality has not been breached but your adversary now has possession and control of your information asset.

Integrity was extended to include Authenticity. An adversary may gain unauthorized access to database and update a table. Internal and external consistency checks (integrity) will pass but table now contains tampered data that’s not authentic or trustworthy.

Availability was extended to include utility. A user may encrypt their private key with a pass phrase. If they forget their pass phrase the usefulness (utility) of the information asset is lost. The information is still available but not usable.